# Can F-Script be used to introspect iOS applications?

Tags: ios, f-script

Can [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/) be used to inspect iOS applications that are running on the simulator or iPhone/iPad hardware? If so, how do I attach the object browser to my custom objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried but could not get F-Script working for iOS. But in the process I found https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect.

It's pretty neat and open source.

Answer (score 3):

Not yet in the trunk but a promising-looking [fork by Steve White](https://github.com/pablomarx/F-Script/commit/19019e31da78a9ef8ecb6eed8c15c79356159266) which I found in Dec 2011 in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/f-script/browse_thread/thread/de47db6dfe0c8e8c?tvc=2) in the Google Group, quoted to save people looking up:

> The standard F-Script distribution doesn't compile on iOS.
>
> Steve White has worked on iOS support and published this: https://github.com/pablomarx/F-Script/commit/19019e31da78a9ef8ecb6eed...
>
> Hopefully we'll be able to integrate it into the main F-Script branch in the future.